# Trying to find a quote: Salt on top of the mountain, instead of snow

Tags: quote-source

Google has failed me. I am trying to recall a quote I read once, which goes something like this: "I have reached the mountain peak I saw in my youth, but it is not snow here; it is only salt." Meaning, I guess, that he had found the success he aspired to but it was not meaningful as he had believed.

I thought perhaps it had been one of those "contextless quotes" from a journalist or essayist, but it may have been a character in a book speaking it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It could be helpful if you added where you initially read this (i.e. medium and time).

Comment: It would probably help me too! I can't remember. It must have been years ago, at least 10 years.